# display more links on more than one page in sap.m.table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sapui5

I have few links(anchor tags) which comes in a div dynamically. If those links goes above    10 in number, I want only first ten to display on page1 and remaining on page2 and so on.

Any help ?

Thanks.

Comment: We can't help if you don't show us any of your code.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is a technique called *paging*. This means that as you said, when the number of items would go beyond a specified limit, only a subset of items would be shown.

To have paging, you need to have these items:

1. Total items count
2. Items count in each page
3. Current page number
4. Some navigation button for navigation between pages

The overall procedure would be something like this:

1. When page loads, you should count all the links you have, then you should decide how many links you're going to show on each page (say you have 376 links and you want to show 10 links per page)
2. You count how many pages you would have (a simple division of total-items/page-items, but you should take the ceiling, in order not to lose your last page)
3. Then you should see which page user has requested (this is your job, and usually occurs in passing parameters via HTTP AJAX request)
4. Now to show items of that page, you simply should skip the items in previous page, then take 10 items and render them.

Comment: Thanks Saeed for your help. I got this working with a property in sap.m.table in SAPUI5.